# When developing a plugin for intellij IDEA, how can your plugin change settings of the user's idea?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, plugins

I am trying to make an intellij idea plugin that reads settings from a dotfile and applies them. I am trying to learn how to apply the settings. For example, let's say I want to change the `font size` to a certain value in the user's editor. How do I do this? I have found information on creating your own custom settings in the docs (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/settings-tutorial.html#creating-the-appsettingstate-implementation) but I have not found how to change settings that already exist in the editor.

I'm using Kotlin.